# HTML Stuck with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I really need your help. I'm learning HTML, and I stuck with the shortest code in the world. For some reason, inline is not working when I use an exteral CSS file, but it does when I used the CSS Code In the HTML file. I even looked in many forums, wasted like four or five hours searching for an answer, and the things that worked for the others it doesn't do the for me. So, if someone can give me a hand with this, i'll be really thankfull.

Here is the code:

```css
li {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel: "stylesheet" href: "test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>ABOUT US</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It even works here! I tried run the code one second ago. It should work. Why is not working? Am I doing something wrong? I use Chrome and Firefox, Brackets as HTML Editor, but I also tried doing it in Notepad, and using inline instead of inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=`, not `:`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
```

Comment: Oh, how can I be so stupid! I didn't see it, I so embarrased right now. Thanks a lot man, now I can keep learning :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML attributes use an `=` for their values, not a `:`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
```

This would have been picked up if you had [used a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel: "stylesheet" href: "test.css">
```

Is wrong, change it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I want to kill my self now. I cant believe i didnt' see it.

Comment: It happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Your link tag is wrong

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
```